# Set div width and resize when it doesn't fit on the screen for absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to set a fixed width to a div, for example 200px. I want the div then to always have 200px, except when the current window has not enough space for it.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid;
}
.fixedWidth {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.noWidth {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedWidth">
  lalala lala lalala lalala
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="noWidth">
  alala lala alal lala
</div>
```

Then the following problem can be seen when the screen gets smaller:

[image: Screencap]

The first div does not resize and text falls outside the screen.

I noticed, the behaviour I am trying to achieve is basically max-width for a normal div, but this doesn't work for absolute positioned divs.

Since for normal divs it is possible to do this without media queries, I am searching for a solution without media queries, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
.fixedWidth {
    max-width:200px; 
    width: 100%;
 }
```

This will mean it is 200px until the screen is not large enough

Answer (score 3):

```
.fixedWidth {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

just add `max-width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the width content to follow width of current content you should make class style that have width 100% 
sry for bad english
it doesnot matter what kind of position you choose

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this class to the fixed width element.

```
#wrapper {
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another div with relative position inside the div with the absolute position.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid;
}
.fixedWidth {
  position: absolute;
}
.sizefit{
  position:relative;
  max-width:200px;
  width:100%;
}
.noWidth {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedWidth">
<div class="sizefit">
 lalala lala lalala lalala
</div>
 
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="noWidth">
  alala lala alal lala
</div>
```